# Well-formed formula, systematically rule out

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Does the following formula is or is not a well-formed formula of the language of set theory?     $a\in (A\subset B)$ and in either case How to systemtically tackle the above question?

Comment: What is the language of set theory for you? Because for me it's only the binary relation $\in$ (and equality is part of the logic).

Comment: $(A\subset B)$ is not a term.

Comment: But, How systematically you can tell that "(A ⊂ B)"is not a term? André Nicolas

Comment: Intuitively "a∈(A⊂B)"  does not make sense and I'm almost sure that formally or systematically "a∈(A⊂B)" is not a term just as you said André Nicolas .So is it right to say then that A⊂B does not denote an operation between the sets A and B?

Comment: @user339662: Do you have an actual definition of "terms" to work with? Often they end with something like "nothing else is a term", and it's then just a question of checking that $(A\subset B)$ does not match any of the positive cases.

Comment: No I do not have an actual definition of "term", Do you have some pdfs or bibliography  which contains  the rules for constructing terms in set theory?

Comment: See e.g. Stephen Simpson, [Foundations of Mathematics](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/fom.pdf) (2009), **Ch.5**.

Answer (score 1):

In the language of set theory $a \in A$ is a formula "built up" with the two *terms* (i.e."names"): $a$ and $A$, and a binary *relation*: $\in$.

It works like: "John is the son of David".

The same for the formula $A \subset B$; it has two terms: $A,B$, because also the relation: $\subset$ is a binary one.

Also this one has the "logical form" of: "David is the brother of Tom".

The sintax is quite simple; you cannot write:

> "John is the son of (David is the brother of Tom)"

because the relations hold between humans and not between sentences.

The same for the formulae above; they use symbols for relations: $\in, \subset$ which needs names for objects (i.e. sets).

Comment: OK. I understand what you are saying here, So is it right to conclude then that the definition of subset does not give a new set from two old ones unlike the definition of union and intersection ?

Comment: Does the definition of subset only give us a "criteria" for decide whether or not some set is indeed a subset of another set?

Comment: @user339662 - YES; $A \subset B$ **iff** "for all $x$, if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$".

Comment: And YES for the previous comment: $A \cup B$ is a *term*, i.e. a "name" for a new set built up from the sets $A$ and $B$, while $A \subset B$ is a "sentence". The difference is like that between the sentence: "John is father of Peter" and the locution "the father of John and Mary".

Answer (score 0):

The writing correct is as follow: $ \quad a \in A \subset B $, within parenthesis. Or:$\quad a\in A$, such that $ A \subset B $.